# How to install RTL8125 Ethernet controller kernel module or driver for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers

Back Story: I built a new computer, using the MSI Z490 A Pro motherboard. It comes with a RTL8125 2.5G Ethernet Controller. I decided to install Ubuntu 20.04 for this build. This distro doesn't seem to come with necesssary driver for this controller. I don't have wifi either. If part of solution is tethering with bluetooth I could give that a shot, but I would prefer to learn with driver from usb stick if possible.

I have no Linux or programming experience, except a bit of front-end web dev., so you're dealing with a novice, but I started to read and learn about Ubuntu and linux, so far I got the thing installed and I'm getting to know commands, command prompt, terminal in general. I believe I would know how to get it going with clear step-by-step instructions, I have a generally good grasp of the basics of how its structured (if I qualify to say that, lol).

Typing in terminal

```
lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
```

I get the name of my Ethernet controller, `RTL8125 2.5G` ...and also it shows at bottom: `kernel modules: r8169`.

Typing in terminal:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

says:

```
network unclaimed
```

and shows Ethernet Controller RTL8125 info.

Here is the link to realtek website: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software

On the Realtek website there is a driver for RTL8125 for linux. I tried following instructions, however they assume people are experts, or info ommited. But I got stuck on third step..

First step: unpack the tarball,

Second step: "Change to the directory: # cd r8125-8.aaa.bb"

Third step:

> If you are running the target kernel, then you should be able to do: # ./autorun.sh

So I decided to make a new directory and put all content of driver(r8125-8.aaa.bb) in it.
New directory path: `~/Downloads/Drivers`

Then I used `chmod 777` in terminal to give executive permissions to all files from driver folder. Then I tried to do third step and didn't seem to work.

Is there something I need to do with NetworkManager directory?
Should I make a new kernel module somehow?
What about dkms? What does that have to do with this problem?

Comment: What 20.04 media was used?   There are two kernel stacks offered (GA & HWE) which are chosen by installation media (for desktops) however you can select for server installs.  Drivers are actually *kernel modules* thus relate to the stack choice made... but you've given no specifics on your choice (ie. media used)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you for your rerply! I apologize for my limited scope.. So i just set up a bootable drive in usb stick using rufus, and downloaded version 20.04 from ubuntu web site, where it says Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS. I installed the larger version(with games and productivity apps).  website:https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop#download  I'm quite sure I didn't install server version.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, on top right corner of desktop there is no network connectivity button, such as I see online on users' desktops ( youtube). @guiverc thanks for the clarification on drivers and kernel modules!

Comment: so I ran sudo ./autorun.sh from driver folder which I put in Drivers directory. It said: "Check old driver and unload it. Build the module and install." I'm guessing it wants me to get rid of r8169 kernel module and make/install new kernel module for rtl8125. Where do I go to remove old module, how do I make new one?

Comment: When you run the `sudo ./autorun.sh` it will automatically unload the driver and build and install the new one.  It is only wording that they use in the installer.

Comment: @Terrance, oh I see, :). I did that and it worked. Thank you!! Also i disabled Secure Boot from BIOS screen.